# What is the difference between capacity and maxCapacity in StringBuilder constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, stringbuilder

There is a **constructor** in **StringBuilder** class (int32, int32). You see there are two parameters **capacity** and **maxCapacity** respectively.

I have tried to search the difference between capacity and maxCapacity in StringBuilder constructor. But, I didn't get anything to understand that constructor. I have found documentation on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbb08bby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Still, I don't understand why it is required and what is the use of these parameters. Some question still in my mind that where should I use this constructor? And does it help to improve my application's performance?

Comment: Capacity is the starting size of the buffer ... but it can grow ... MaxCapacity is the maximum size of the buffer.

Comment: Read remarks statement in your link which you have provided

Comment: @NagarajS I have read that. "But, still I don't understand. what is the use of these parameters? And where should I use it? does it effects on Application's performance?"

Comment: hehehe.. i got downvote on my question.. downvoters prefers to down vote the question first rather than answer. b`coz they have to pay for that. I don't know who down voted my question but, he/she has not seen that I have also posted an answer to my own question. I think the matter has hurt someone. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the MSDN : [`StringBuilder(int,int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbb08bby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Initializes a new instance of the StringBuilder class that starts with
>   a specified capacity and can grow to a specified maximum.

So the `Capcity` is the size with which it has tobe started/created and `MaxCapacity` is the Limitation of the `Stringbuilder`.

Example 1: Try the following example one by one

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(3, 5);
str.Append("1");      //no error as Length 1 <= max limit 5         
str.Append("12");     //no error as Length 2 <= max limit 5           
str.Append("123");    //no error as Length 3 <= max limit 5   
str.Append("1234");   //no error as Length 4 <= max limit 5        
str.Append("12345");  //no error as Length 5 <= max limit 5        
str.Append("123456"); //error as Length 6 is not <= max limit 5
```

Example 2: Try the following example all at once

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(3, 5);
str.Append("1");      //no error as str Length 1 <= max limit 5         
str.Append("12");     //no error as str Length 3 <= max limit 5           
str.Append("123");    //error as str Length 6 is not <= max limit 5
```

**EDIT:**

Yes `MaxCapacity` is seldomly used.

**StringBuilder(int Capacity)** : with `Capacity` parameter it creates the `StringBuilder` object in memory.

as soon as user adds items and if the size exceeds its capacity limit then it allocates more memory to accomdate the exceeded characters and it keeps growing untill unless there is no problem with the memory.

**StringBuilder(int Capacity,int maxCapacity)** : it does the same as above one parameter Constructor but before creating/increasing its runtime memory to accomdate exceeded characters it checks for `MAXCAPACITY` limit ,if it exceeds the `MAXCAPACITY` limit then throws the `Exception`.

---

From the below commnets : As @Sriram said `MaxCapacity` parameter has nothing to do with memory allocation.

Comment: Does it effects on virtual memory. if I define maxCapacity in while creating object of StringBuilder?

Comment: i don't know what do you mean by effect, but i think it does nothing morethan what StringBuilder does with only Capacity parameter, but it checks for MaxLimit and throws exception once if the maxlimit exceeds, so it would be usefull when you want to restrict certain parameter values to certain limit.

Comment: @Nimesh I guess you're asking whether `maxCapacity` will allocate memory immediately? No; It is just a variable which will be used to check before doing an allocation.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel That's what i want to know.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi Your example is very helpful to understand maxCapacity in StringBuilder. Yes, I got it.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi I have tried your above example in my console application but, it gives error while appending "123" into stringbuilder. the error is **ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled - capacity was less than the current size.
Parameter name: requiredLength**

Comment: @Nimesh: are you trying all the statements at once?

Comment: @Nimesh: check my edited answer.i thnk you are looking for `Example2`

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi I got it. The problem is my StringBuilder did not get reset. Thanks Sudhakar.

Comment: @Nimesh: you are welcome dear :) glad tobe help of you

Answer (score 3):

**Difference Between**

For *capacity*

If the number of characters to be stored in the current instance exceeds this capacity value, the **StringBuilder** object **allocates additional memory** to store them.

However, string builder class provides an efficient way 
to repeatedly append bits of string to already constructed object.

StringBuilder is Useful if We want to Make a Big String

**Capacity** represents the contiguous memory allocated to the **StringBuilder**. Capacity can be >= length of the string. When more data is appended to the **StringBuilder** than the capacity, **StringBuilder** automatically increases the capacity. Since the capacity has exceeded (that is contiguous memory is filled up and no more buffer room is available), a larger buffer area is allocated and data is copied from the original memory to this new area.

It does not copy data to new 'instance' but to new 'memory location'. The instance remains the same but points to the new memory location.

Default capacity of **StringBuilder** if not specified during creation is **16**

For *maxCapacity*

If the number of characters to be stored in the current instance exceeds this maxCapacity value, the **StringBuilder** object **does not allocate additional memory**, but instead throws an exception.

The maximum capacity for this implementation is Int32.MaxValue. However, this value is implementation-specific and might be different in other or later implementations

[MSDN maxCapacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.text.stringbuilder.maxcapacity%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I have read this in msdn as i have mentioned in my question. but, point is why it is require? and where should i use it?

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar yes this will gives me additional detail of StringBuilder Constructor.

Answer (score 3):

It's important to understand that objects like a StringBuilder have to provide internal storage for their data.  That is generally going to be an array.  Usually, the size of that array will be fairly small.  As you add data to the object, whenever the data grows beyond the bounds of that array, more space must be allocated.  If you specify an initial `capacity` then the internal array will initially be created with that size.  That means that there will be less need to resize the array as data is added.  If you know that you will be adding at least N characters to the StringBuilder then it makes sense to specify N as the initial `capacity` to avoid unnecessary resizing.  `maxCapacity` is the largest size that that internal array can be increased to.

Answer (score 3):

After reading all answers, Finally, I understand the difference between capacity and maxCapacity. Now I am trying an example to determine the time of process in different scenario. So, I going to share something about StringBuilder Constructor. I have tested StringBuilder.Append method in following cases and i got some results.

The application code is simple

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stp = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
stp.Start();
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder()
str.Append("12345");  
Console.WriteLine(stp.ElapsedTicks);
```

In the declaration of StringBuilder i have used following constructors.

ie. `StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(3, 5)`

```
 1. (int32,int32) : (capacity, maxCapacity)
 2. (int32) : (capacity)
 3. () : Without capacity (No Parameters)
```

The results are as follows

```
Trial   (capacity,maxCapacity)      (capacity)      Without Capacity
1       31018                       25259           28847
2       32682                       25025           24635
3       32513                       27404           25168
4       31330                       26013           24986
5       31616                       24050           25324
```

if i create an object of StringBuilder with maxCapacity then it takes more time to append text then other two cases. But, there is no difference between declaring object with capacity and without capacity. I think it takes some time in checking the maximum capacity of defined string builder class object.

Answer (score 1):

- **capacity** is for the starting capacity of the StringBuilder. Capacity is the current memory that is allocated by the StringBuilder. If you add text, the amount of memory that is allocated needs to be increased if the current capacity is exceeded. This takes some time. In order to avoid resizing the memory of the StringBuilder, you can set it to a higher value and by that increase performance of your application. If you know before how long the strings that you want to build are at maximum with a high probability, this is a good starting point as you reduce the number of memory reallocations.
- **maxCapacity** marks the maximum capacity of the StringBuilder and allows to limit the amount of memory that is used by the StringBuilder. If you add data to it, the memory won't be increased over this limit, but an exception is thrown. So you can avoid to run into memory problems if somehow your application wants to add to much to the StringBuilder. However, please note that this limit is not respected under some circumstances from .NET 4 (see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.maxcapacity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

So using this constructor allows you to both increase your performance and set a limit. From my experience, I've mostly used the constructor that allows setting the initial capacity and have set a maxCapacity seldom. But you might want to use this constructor if you append **data from unknown sources to a StringBuilder**, e.g. from a file that is provided by users in order to react early and more gracefully than handling an OutOfMemoryException allows. So using this constructor also increases the robustness of your application.